# Caption above subtables with subcaption package breaks numbering of following table

Tags: numbering, subcaption

I use the subcaption package to display multiple tables side by side.
My document follows the convention of putting table captions above the table and I would like to keep this for the meta caption at least.

If I put the caption above the subtable entries, the following table is skipping one increment in the numbering like this:

Captions below:
Table 1
Table 2

Captions above: 
Table 1
Table 3

This is an example of the situation that produces the wrong numbering:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,toc=listof,toc=bib,abstract=true,parskip=half]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\chapter{firstchapter}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{A table with caption on top}\label{tab:1}
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
\caption{A subtable}\label{tab:1a}
{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\ $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
\caption{Another subtable}\label{tab:1b}
{\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\ $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
{\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\ $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}}

\caption{Any other table}\label{tab:2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Am I using something wrong here or is this a bug in the subcaption package? Any Input would be appreciated, I would rather not "fix" the counter manually after the table or change packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to alternate between top and bottom captions, you will have to set `\captionabove` instead of the upper `\caption`.

If you want to have them all on top, just set the option `captions=tableheading` to your documentclass and add the captions as you would normally do.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[%
    ,parskip=half
    %,captions=tableheading
    ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\chapter{firstchapter}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \captionabove{A table with caption on top}\label{tab:1}
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
        \subcaption{A subtable}\label{tab:1a}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\\midrule
            0 & 0 & 0 \\
            1 & 1 & 1 \\    
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}{.5\linewidth}\centering
        \subcaption{Another subtable}\label{tab:1b}
        \begin{tabular}{c c c}
            $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\\midrule
            0 & 0 & 0 \\
            1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}%
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\\midrule
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Any other table}\label{tab:2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm amazed that I missed the existence of both the command and the option. I guess once I had figured out that simply putting the `\caption` where you want it to appear I never questioned if that was actually the right way. So this breaking with subcaption was a blessing actually :D