# Position of \caption gets counter incremented twice

Tags: tables, subcaption

So, this example was bugging me:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,DIV=9,BCOR=2cm,openright,parskip=never]{scrbook}
% \documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% \setcapindent{0pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{afterpage}
% \usepackage{pdflscape}    % FOR DISPLAY
\usepackage{lscape}     % FOR PRINTING

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\blindtext

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
        \toprule
        10 & 20 \\ \midrule
        30 & 40 \\
        50 & 60 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{First table.}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[p]
        \centering
        \caption{Summary of the answers to the demographics questionnaires}\label{tab:st3:demographics}

        \subcaptionbox{A1: Have you studied music?}{
            \begin{tabular}{@{}rccc}
                \toprule
                & {\bf\small no}
                & {\bf\small informally}
                & {\bf\small formally} \\ \midrule
                {\bf\small beginners}       & {\bf 7} & 5 &       2  \\
                {\bf\small non-beginners}   &      0  & 1 & {\bf  9}  \\
                {\bf\small total}           &      7  & 6 & {\bf 11} \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        }\qquad
        \subcaptionbox{A2: Do you play a musical instrument?}{
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                \toprule
                {\bf\small no}
                & {\bf\small one}
                & {\bf\small more} \\ \midrule
                {\bf 10} & 3 &      1  \\
                      0  & 2 & {\bf 8} \\
                {\bf 10} & 5 &      9  \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        }\qquad
        \subcaptionbox{A3: Have you ever composed original music?}{
            \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                \toprule
                  \textbf{\small never}
                & \textbf{\small occasionally}
                & \textbf{\small often} \\ \midrule
                {\bf 11} & 3 &      0  \\
                {\bf  4} & 2 & {\bf 4} \\
                {\bf 15} & 5 &      4  \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        }

        \vspace{\baselineskip}

        \subcaptionbox{A2.1: How would you rate your skills on your best instrument?}{
            \begin{tabular}{@{}rccccc}
                \toprule
                & {\bf\small 1} & {\bf\small 2} & {\bf\small 3} & {\bf\small 4} & {\bf\small 5} \\ \midrule
                {\bf\small beginners}     & {\bf 4} & 1 &      1  & 0 & 0 \\
                {\bf\small non-beginners} &      1  & 2 & {\bf 6} & 0 & 1 \\
                {\bf\small total}         &      5  & 3 & {\bf 7} & 0 & 1 \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        }\qquad
        \subcaptionbox{A3.1: How confident are you in your ability to compose original music?}{
            \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
                \toprule
                {\bf\small 1}  & {\bf\small 2} & {\bf\small 3} & {\bf\small 4} & {\bf\small 5} \\ \midrule
                {\bf  8} & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
                {\bf  3} & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
                {\bf 11} & 7 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}

\blindtext

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
        \toprule
        70 & 80 \\ \midrule
        90 & 100 \\
        110 & 120 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Last table.}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The 'Last table' was getting numbered 1.4 even though it should have been numbered 1.3. On a whim, I moved the `\caption` of the huge table right before the `\end{table}` command, and suddenly I got 'Table 1.3. Last table'.

My question is: why?

more minimal example (for comment below)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

x

\begin{table}
    \centering
t1
    \caption{First table.}
\end{table}

x
\begin{table}[p]
\caption{zz}
\subcaptionbox{A1}{???}
\end{table}

x

\begin{table}
    \centering
t last
    \caption{Last table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why the commented (pdf)lscape? that should not be necessary, also why `\bf` ?

Comment: I switch between lscape and pdflscape and produce a pdf for screen and one for printing. I found out that the landscaped pages produced with pdflscape sometimes get printed upside down by some pdf readers. As I don't know what the printing services are using, I didn't want to take any chances. I forgot to remove the two lines in the MWE. Re \bf, I used www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables to generate the tables quickly and haven't touched up yet. They work for now, I'll leave that for when I'll go through the source with a fine comb.

Comment: I added a more minimal example with unrelated packages removed. It looks like an interaction between scrbook and subcaption, it doesn't happen if you use book instead. I don't know the koma classes that well, don't they have sub caption features without loading subcaption package?

Comment: I don't know the koma classes very much as well, so I figured I'd use them for the layout, and do everything else with packages for which I can find examples online quickly.

Comment: send a bug report to the table generator! `\bf` has not been defined by default in latex since 1993, they are due for an update it seems.

Comment: I'm nit sure that is a good approach, one of the main ideas behind classes like memorir and koma is that they build in much more functionality, that means that you don't need to load so many add-on packages, but that you are more likely to get clashes if you do load packages that are designed to patch the standard classes to ad features that have already been added.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll look into that for the final submission. Right now, I'm supposed to submit a complete draft in two days, so I guess I'll send in whatever works and refine it later :)

Comment: The `subcaption` is designed to work perfectly with the KOMA-Script document classes as well, and sub-captions are not part of KOMA-Script. So it's IMHO totally ok to load this add-on package.

Comment: The main problem is that the LaTeX concept of `\caption` is IMHO totally broken. (The counter should be incremented at the beginning of the environment, not at `\caption`. And `\caption` should not exist, it should be an option of `table` instead.) Since sub-captions need to have the correct `table` counter they need to know it the caption will be above or below the content. But it can either guess or have to rely on user settings (like KOMA offers them). If the user actually behaves against his own settings, you will get a strange behavior like here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already answered here: [Caption above subtables with subcaption package breaks numbering of following table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267475/caption-above-subtables-with-subcaption-package-breaks-numbering-of-following-ta)

Some additional background: Nobody prevents you from placing more-than-one `\caption` inside a `table`. So the `subcaption` package is taking the position of the caption into respect. In your case, you wrote (with KOMA-Script option `captions=tablesignature` active):

```
\caption{zz}
\subcaptionbox{A1}{???}
```

What happens here: `\caption` will increase the `table` counter. Afterwards `\subcaptionbox` sees that there was a `\caption` right in front of it and assumes that you are starting a second pair of content+caption in the `table` environment since you have told KOMA-Script that the caption is always typeset *after* the content. So it increases the `table` counter. In fact you have two pairs of content+caption in this particular `table`: Empty content + caption, and `\subcaptionbox` content without extra caption. If a `\caption` would follow this would not increase the `table` counter again since the very first `\subcaptionbox` has already done this. Try it out for yourself:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

x

\begin{table}
    \centering
t1
    \caption{First table.}
\end{table}

x
\begin{table}[p]
\caption{zz}
\subcaptionbox{A1}{???}
\caption{zz} % This caption added, note that it does *not* increase the table counter
\end{table}

x

\begin{table}
    \centering
t last
    \caption{Last table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

BTW: For debugging counter problems with sub-captions it's always a good idea to put the actual figure/table number into the sub-numbering as well:

```
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}
\renewcommand\thesubtable{\thetable\alph{subtable}}
```

This way you can clearly see which command actually increases the figure resp. table counter. (If you are done with debugging simply comment these two lines out.)

Comment: I suspected something like that, I just thought that captions and subcaptions worked on different counters. However, I don't see where I said `captions=tablesignature`, is it a default?

Comment: Yes, `captions=tablesignature` is the default, see section 3.20 of the KOMA-Script documentation. And yes, captions and subcaptions work on different counters, but they are connected to each other, just like section and subsection: The subsection counter output contains the section counter (for example "3.2" where "3" is the section and "2" the subsection counter), and it gets reset when a new section starts. Same with the table and subtable counter, the only difference is that the subtable counter output does not contain the table counter by default (but you can change that).

Comment: ...furtheremore the connection between table and subtable counter is important for hyperref anchors/links (since the links should jump to the correct table when clicked). And it is important for the "List of Tables" if the sub-tables are included in the list as well. So you see, the sub-table needs to know the corresponding table counter, even if the `\caption` which increments the table counter comes after the sub-caption. (This is a little bit tricky since `\caption` and not `table` will increase the table counter.)